# Cant fetch data from API while building app in flutter

Tags: api, flutter

Can someone help me, I am getting this error while running my code in vs code, android virtual device cannot fetch data from backend API[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mnVO.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mnVO.jpg)

Comment: Is the API running on your PC? If yes, what address and port?

Comment: First, check Internet status in your virtual device, sometimes it is disabled with no connection. Second, check if your HTTP request is valid by running it in your terminal.

Comment: Also, copy the text of the errors into the body of the answer, don't just link the images